# How do I move dynamically allocated data from an object to another?

Tags: c++, c++11, memory, move-semantics, temporary

I have an Array class written with RAII in mind (super simplified for the purpose of this example):

```
struct Array
{
    Array(int size) {
        m_size = size;
        m_data = new int[m_size];
    }

    ~Array() {
        delete[] m_data;
    }

    int* m_data = nullptr;
    int  m_size = 0;
};
```

Then I have a function that takes a reference to an Array and does some operations on it. I use a temporary Array `temp` to perform the processing, because for several reasons I can't work directly with the reference. Once done, I would like to transfer the data from the temporary Array to the real one:

```
void function(Array& array)
{
    Array temp(array.m_size * 2);

    // do heavy processing on `temp`...

    array.m_size = temp.m_size;
    array.m_data = temp.m_data;
}
```

The obvious problem is that `temp` goes out of scope at the end of the function: its destructor is triggered, which in turn deletes the memory. This way `array` would contain non-existent data.

So what is the best way to "move" the ownership of data from an object to another?

Comment: The "best way" would be to completely avoid raw pointers and arrays and use `std::vector`.

Comment: Or if you really insist on doing this (e.g.: because it's an exercise) then you need to implement your own copy and move constructors (see: [The rule of three/five/zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three))

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you want is move construction or move assignment for your array class, which saves you redundant copies. Also, it will help you to use `std::unique_ptr` which will take care of move semantics for allocated memory for you, so that you don't need to do any memory allocation directly, yourself. You will still need to pull up your sleeves and follow the ["rule of zero/three/five"](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three), which in our case is the rule of five (copy & move constructor, copy & move assignment operator, destructor).

So, try:

```
class Array {
public:
    Array(size_t size) : m_size(size) {
        m_data = std::make_unique<int[]>(size);
    }

    Array(const Array& other) : Array(other.size) {
        std::copy_n(other.m_data.get(), other.m_size, m_data.get());
    }

    Array(Array&& other) : m_data(nullptr) {
        *this = other;
    } 

    Array& operator=(Array&& other) {
        std::swap(m_data, other.m_data);
        std::swap(m_size,other.m_size);
        return *this;
    }

    Array& operator=(const Array& other) {
        m_data = std::make_unique<int[]>(other.m_size);
        std::copy_n(other.m_data.get(), other.m_size, m_data.get());
        return *this;
    }

    ~Array() = default;

    std::unique_ptr<int[]>  m_data;
    size_t                  m_size;
};
```

(Actually, it's a bad idea to have `m_size` and `m_data` public, since they're tied together and you don't want people messing with them. I would also template that class on the element type, i.e. `T` instead of `int` and use `Array<int>`)

Now you can implement your function in a very straightforward manner:

```
void function(Array& array)
{
    Array temp { array }; // this uses the copy constructor

    // do heavy processing on `temp`...

    std::swap(array, temp); // a regular assignment would copy
}
```

Comment: Looks great. You are not using copy/move ctor/move assignment operator/... directly, so I guess they are required by std::swap to work, right?

Comment: I think you should define deleter for your unique_ptr that should `delete[] ptr`

Comment: @mahdi_12167: IIRC the array version of `make_unique` takes care of that.

Comment: Why do you do `...std::move(other.m_data));` if _other_ is taken as r-value?. Do you really need to specify _std::move_?.

Comment: And last question, assigments operators methods should also return _*this_, shouldn't they?. Thank you.

Comment: @Jules: You're right. But - you can have just edited the answer yourself (and it would even have gotten you a couple of reputation points, and progress towards a badge).

Answer (score 2):

if you insist on your example format, then you are missing a couple of things. you need to make sure that the temp array does not destroy memory reused by the non-temp array.

```
 ~Array() {
    if (md_data != nullptr) 
         delete [] m_data;
 }
```

and the function needs to do clean move

```
void function(Array& array)
{
    Array temp(array.m_size * 2);

    // do heavy processing on `temp`...

    array.m_size = temp.m_size;
    array.m_data = temp.m_data;
    temp.m_data = nullptr;
    temp.m_size = 0;
}
```

To make it more c++ like, you can do multiple things. i.e. in the array you can create member function to move the data from other array (or a constructor, or assign operator, ...)

```
  void Array::move(Array &temp) {
      m_size = temp.m_size;
      temp.m_size = 0;
      m_data = temp.m_data;
      temp.m_data = 0;
  }
```

in c++11 and higher you can create a move constructor and return your value from the function:

```
 Array(Array &&temp) {
      do your move here
 }
 Array function() {
      Array temp(...);
      return temp;
 }
```

there are other ways as well.

Comment: `if (md_ata != nullptr)` is unnecessary, nothing bad can happen when calling `delete[]` on a null pointer

Comment: Also you don't require a move constructor for (N)RVO

Comment: Upvote for the less C++11-ish way of doing it, in case of need